# Why do some Iframes applications Work in IE8 and others dont

Tags: internet-explorer-8, iframe

I have a simple scenario below it works in XP ie6 but doesn't work in Windows 7 IE8..

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://m.dabr.co.uk" width="800" Height="600" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Why?  and how do i fix it?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seems it was a cookies issue with the default security in IE8